# Is it possible to add a Splash Screen to an iPhone Web Application launched from the Home Page?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I have created an iPhone Web Application (written in HTML/JavaScript) that can be added to the home page via a launcher button.

It takes about 5-7 seconds for this application to start.

When starting it displays a previous screen of the application (not always the last one the user is on).

Is there anyway to provide some sort of splash screen to let the user know the application is starting and they should wait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the apple documentation it is possible starting from iPhone OS 3.0 by using:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">
```

see [Specifying a Startup Image](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

> On iPhone OS, similar to native
>   applications, you can specify a
>   startup image that is displayed while
>   your web application launches

Comment: Thank you Dror - this capability is available in iPhone OS 3.0+